# In Apps Script identifying instances of a script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using apps Script Triggers to get a script to run more than once in a convoluted attempt to do threading.

It works like this. When the script runs it sets a trigger to run the same script every minute, so in theory you could have 5 instances running at once before the 6 minute timeout. This is actually working - not as smoothly as I would like as sometimes there are none running for some reason.

Anyhow I want to see how many scripts are running at any moment and identify them. I could not find an identifier for an instance of  script, although there is a script identifier, ScriptApp.getScriptId()

Is there any way to identify an instance?

Comment: Use the event object that all triggered functions get: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#time-driven_events you'll have to make your own id based on the activation time values

Answer (score 0):

You can generate and store a random string as an identifier for each run. This will let you count running instances: using [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) to register runs is an easy way to do this. If a run crashes or gets killed for some reason it won't be able to clean up after itself, so for safety we can also have the function which counts active runs clear out zombie properties.

```
/**
 * Generate a random identifier from multiple common words
 */
function memorableIdentifier(len) {
  var tokens = 'able bad big case child company day different early eye' +
      'fact few first good government great group hand high important
      'large last life little long man new next number old' +
      'other own part person place point problem public right same' +
      'small thing time way week woman work world year young'.split(' ');
  var out = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    out.push(tokens[Math.floor(Math.random() * tokens.length)]);
  }
  return out.join('-');  // generates identifers like 'life-place-week'
}

/**
 * This is the function you trigger every minute
 */
function scriptTriggerHandler(e) {
  // Make a script property for this Uid's start
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var runIdentifier = memorableIdentifier(5);
  props.setProperty(runIdentifier, new Date());
  /**
   * DO ACTUAL STUFF HERE
   */
  props.deleteProperty(runIdentifier);
}

/**
 * Count script properties with plausibly recent timestamp values.
 * Also cleans up stale properties. Alter this if you use script
 * properties for other purposes.
 */
function countActiveRuns() {
  var TIMEOUT = 6 * 60 * 1000;  // Six minutes in milliseconds
  var active = 0;
  var now = new Date();
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var propKeys = props.getKeys();
  for (var i = 0; i < propKeys.length; i++) {
    var triggerUid = propKeys[i];
    var startTime = props[triggerUid];
    if (now - startTime > TIMEOUT) {
      // We have found a stale entry
      props.deleteProperty(triggerUid);
    } else {
      active += 1;
    }
  }
  return active;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Isn't this the same as just storing a new Date() in script properties every time a script runs? triggerUid is always the same number because it;s always the same trigger calling the script.

Comment: Oh interesting, I hadn't noticed that. If that's the case, then instead using e.triggerUid, just make up a random identifier at the beginning of each run, and delete that property at the end.

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer to instead generate memorable "correct-horse-battery-staple" type identifiers for each run. You could pass this ID around and use it to tag logs too, if your logging is messy and you need to keep runs separated.

Comment: Thanks jjjoe. If google doesn't provide a script instance property we can always make one :)